# FOSUserBundle Login, Registration, ForgotPassword on the same page

Tags: php, symfony, templates, overriding, fosuserbundle

I've overrided the default layout of FOSUserBundle by placing a layout.html.twig in app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views.

I also have overrided some other templates (like login, register and resetting password) by placing new files in the corresponding directory:

```
app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\layout.html.twig
app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Registration\register.html.twig
app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Resetting\request.html.twig
app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig
```

I would like to render the register-form, the login-form and the reset-password-form on the same page. For that I'm using twigs render controller method:

```
<div class="login" data-lbg="teal">
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }} // foo
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }} // bar
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:request')) }} // baz
</div>
```

However, this just outputs the word "foo" and doesn't extend my layout.html.twig. So it just gives me a blank page with "foo" on it.

Is there something broken or am I doing something wrong?

Best
Christian

Comment: The FOSUserBundle actions are meant to be used as standalone, not to be included with render(controller()) function. I think that the only way you can do this is creating your action, creating the 3 needed forms and displaying all forms in your template. You should set the "action" of each form to the correspondant bundle's route

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I decided to solve this similar to your proposal. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created an specific controller for rendering the three forms, which seems to be working. In the corresponding view script:

```
{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:request')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, if there are validation errors, the user will be redirected to /login, /register and /resetting/request, which templates are not extending the login layout. At the moment, the user get a white page with the form on it. :/